# JavaFX TriangleMesh rendering incorrectly

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I built an OBJ to JavaFX triangle mesh parser and imported the monkey head sample model from blender but it doesn't render correctly. It almost seems to have a wallhack like effect. This link has the obj I'm trying to import as well as a video showing the problem. [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzW0t4K6XI4gWlExS0xXLW1UbEE). This is the code I'm using.

```
if(tmp.startsWith("v ")) {
    split = tmp.split(" ");
    verticies.add(Float.parseFloat(split[1]));
    verticies.add(Float.parseFloat(split[2]));
    verticies.add(Float.parseFloat(split[3]));
} else if(tmp.startsWith("f ")) {
    split = tmp.split("f |/\\d*/\\d* *");
    faces.add(Integer.parseInt(split[1]) - 1);
    faces.add(Integer.parseInt(split[2]) - 1);
    faces.add(Integer.parseInt(split[3]) - 1);
    if(split.length > 4) {
        faces.add(Integer.parseInt(split[3]) - 1);
        faces.add(Integer.parseInt(split[4]) - 1);
        faces.add(Integer.parseInt(split[1]) - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was really really simple and had nothing to do with my OBJ code. The `Scene` constructor takes a boolean parameter to determine whether or not depth buffering is enabled. If you use a constructor that doesn't take a depth buffering parameter it defaults to false. Setting it to true completely fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are already a few 3D model JavaFX importers out there.

You can check the [3DViewer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/c3f242e6146c/apps/samples/3DViewer) project from the OpenJFX project. It is open source.

If you clone the project, build it and run it, you will be able to import your obj file:

[image: 3DViewer]

As you can see, there are no issues with the obj file.

You may have a look at the [code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/c3f242e6146c/apps/samples/3DViewer/src/main/java/com/javafx/experiments/importers/obj) for the OBJ importer, to find out about how an obj file is parsed and converted to a `TriangleMesh`.

Other importers can be found at [interactivemesh.org](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html), but it is not open source.

Regarding the issue you mentioned, you can play with the cull face:

```
meshView.setCullFace(CullFace.BACK);
```

or

```
meshView.setCullFace(CullFace.FRONT);
```

will change the order of winding the triangles, affecting how you see the model. Default is BACK.

Comment: I did play with face culling but that didn't help which is why I posted. Leaving it at BACK works the best.

Comment: Then verify with the OBJImpoter if your code generates the same TrangleMesh